# I am trying to add a child node which is just a key with no attached value. What changes do I need to make to my code to do this?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write data into firebase real time database. The way I would like to structure it is like this.

[image: desired database structure]

The way my database is currently it simply makes the username a child and I cannot add any child nodes under the username.

[image: Current database structure].

Here is the code which writes the data

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             String username = EditUsername.getText().toString();

             if (username.isEmpty() )
             {
                 Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please add some data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
             else
            {
               Toast.makeText(Login.this, "it recognizes the field isn't empty",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 addDataToFirebase(username);
            }
        }
     });
 }

 private void addDataToFirebase(String TheUsername)
{
     Toast.makeText(this, "the addDataToFirebase function is being called",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     users.setUsername(TheUsername);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            reference.setValue(users);

             Toast.makeText(Login.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
             Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Failed to Add data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: "I am trying to add a child node which is just a key with no attached value" Firebase Realtime Database cannot store a key without a value. It creates keys as values are written, and removes them when there's no longer a value under them. --- Outside of that, I'm not sure what your code is trying to do - as we can't see how `users` is initialized and what username was entered. Can you edit your question to show with hard-coded values what you want to write, and what you get out of it in the database, and what you want to get instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.